How to implement reactor Flux in expediagroup graphql like Mono?
I am trying to write datafetcher for Flux in similar fashion as Mono and used the below code to return a CompletableFuture, but this always returns null.? HOw to support Flux in graphql expediagroup
class ReactorQuery : Query {
    fun asynchronouslyDo(): Mono<Int> = Mono.just(1)   
    fun asynchronouslyDoFluxInt(): Flux<Int> = Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
}

class CustomFunctionDataFetcher(target: Any?, fn: KFunction<*>) : FunctionDataFetcher(target, fn) {
    override fun get(environment: DataFetchingEnvironment): Any? = when (val result = super.get(environment)) {
        is Mono<*> -> result.toFuture()
        is Flux<*> -> result.map { it -> Mono.just(it).toFuture() }.collect(Collectors.toList()).toFuture()
        else -> result
    }
}

I have also tried the following and it doesnt work either
class CustomFunctionDataFetcher(target: Any?, fn: KFunction<*>) : FunctionDataFetcher(target, fn) {
    override fun get(environment: DataFetchingEnvironment): Any? {
        val result = super.get(environment)
        when (result) {
            is Mono<*> -> return result.toFuture()
            is Flux<*> -> return result.collect(Collectors.toList()).toFuture()
            else -> return result
        }
    }
}

Error message that I get is:
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] WARN notprivacysafe.graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy - Can't serialize value (/asynchronouslyDoFluxInt) : Expected a value that can be converted to type 'Int' but it was a 'ArrayList'
graphql.schema.CoercingSerializeException: Expected a value that can be converted to type 'Int' but it was a 'ArrayList'
at graphql.scalar.GraphqlIntCoercing.serialiseImpl(GraphqlIntCoercing.java:59)

The way to do this is as follows:
class MonadHooks : SchemaGeneratorHooks {
    override fun willResolveMonad(type: KType): KType = when (type.classifier) {
        Mono::class -> type.arguments.firstOrNull()?.type
        Flux::class -> List::class.createType(type.arguments)      
        Set::class -> List::class.createType(type.arguments)
        else -> type
    } ?: type
}


class CustomFunctionDataFetcher(target: Any?, fn: KFunction<*>) : FunctionDataFetcher(target, fn) {
    override fun get(environment: DataFetchingEnvironment): Any? {
        val result = super.get(environment)
        when (result) {
            is Mono<*> -> return result.toFuture()
            is Flux<*> -> return result.log().collectList().toFuture()
            else -> return result
        }
    }
}

